# angularjs - load dependencies whenever it is required instead of loading all in starting

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJs application, in that I have so many dependency files. all files path i am adding in **index.html** page and all dependencies in **app.js** file. 
So that whenever i will start my application all files get loaded at initialization level
but instead of loading all js files in starting,  I want to load js files when ever it is required

**for ex** -
- I click on home button, so app should load home.js, home.html, and home page related dependencies  only
- similarly when i ll redirect to about us screen,  app should load about us dependencies only

So what should i do to load only respected files instead of loading all files in starting.
I have to load more than 50 js files including controller, directive, services, etc
and all js files having heavy loaded data.
so if I tried to load all files in starting, application become slow

I have tried it with **requirejs**
but is there any other way to do it

Comment: Have you looked into Lazy Loading techniques? Seems to me it's more or less what you want to do.

Comment: first tell us what is size of all your js & html? (not including libraries) and what size of libraries?

Comment: @GabrielLovetro  -  i tried lazy loading technique using requireJs, but I didn't find the better way to do this

Comment: @Petraveryanov I have to load more than 50 js files including controller, directive, services, etc
and all js files having heavy loaded data.

Comment: @ojuskulkarni - I myself haven't used Lazy Loading except for loading hundreds of pictures in a page. For that specific application it worked wonders! I was using ionic/angular (v1), though, so as far as I remember we didn't use requireJS (we used a lazy loading directive/plugin).

Comment: Can you aswer question - 50 js files with size of? Heavy load data (?) - how on Earth this is related to question...